# Sort and return all of nested dictionaries based on specified key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to re-arrange the contents of a nested dictionaries where it will check the value of a specified key.

```
dict_entries = {
    'entries': {
        'AzP746r3Nl': {
            'uniqueID': 'AzP746r3Nl',
            'index': 2,
            'data': {'comment': 'First Plastique Mat.',
                     'created': '17/01/19 10:18',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'plastique_varA',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'plastique_varA',
            'text': 'plastique test',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/mat/plastique_varA/plastique_varA.jpg',
            'type': 'matEntry'
        },  

        'Q2tch2xm6h': {
            'uniqueID': 'Q2tch2xm6h',
            'index': 0,
            'data': {'comment': 'Camino from John Inds.',
                     'created': '03/01/19 12:08',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'camino_H10a',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'camino_H10a',
            'text': 'John Inds : Camino',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/chips/camino_H10a/camino_H10a.jpg',
            'type': 'ChipEntry'
        },

        'ZeqCFCmHqp': {
            'uniqueID': 'ZeqCFCmHqp',
            'index': 1,
            'data': {'comment': 'Prototype Bleu.',
                     'created': '03/01/19 14:07',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'bleu_P23y',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'bleu_P23y',
            'text': 'Bleu : Prototype',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/chips/bleu_P23y/bleu_P23y.jpg',
            'type': 'ChipEntry'
        }
    }
}
```

In my above nested dictionary example, I am trying to check it by the `name` and `created` key (2 functions each) and once it has been sorted, the `index` value will be updated accordingly as well...

Even so, I am able to query for the values of the said key(s):

```
for item in dict_entries.get('entries').values():
    #The key that I am targetting at
    tar_key = item['name']
```

but this is returning me the value of the `name` key and I am unsure on my next step as I am trying to sort by the value of the `name` key and capturing + re-arranging all the contents of the nested dictionaries.

This is my desired output (if checking by `name`):

```
{'entries': {
    'ZeqCFCmHqp': {
            'uniqueID': 'ZeqCFCmHqp',
            'index': 1,
            'data': {'comment': 'Prototype Bleu.',
                     'created': '03/01/19 14:07',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'bleu_P23y',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'bleu_P23y',
            'text': 'Bleu : Prototype',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/chips/bleu_P23y/bleu_P23y.jpg',
            'type': 'ChipEntry'
        }

    'Q2tch2xm6h': {
            'uniqueID': 'Q2tch2xm6h',
            'index': 0,
            'data': {'comment': 'Camino from John Inds.',
                     'created': '03/01/19 12:08',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'camino_H10a',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'camino_H10a',
            'text': 'John Inds : Camino',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/chips/camino_H10a/camino_H10a.jpg',
            'type': 'ChipEntry'
        },

    'AzP746r3Nl': {
            'uniqueID': 'AzP746r3Nl',
            'index': 2,
            'data': {'comment': 'First Plastique Mat.',
                     'created': '17/01/19 10:18',
                     'project': 'EMZ',
                     'name': 'plastique_varA',
                     'version': '1'},
            'name': 'plastique_varA',
            'text': 'plastique test',
            'thumbnail': '/Desktop/mat/plastique_varA/plastique_varA.jpg',
            'type': 'matEntry'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `item['name]` is missing a quote. I don't follow what you mean by "trying to check it". What is your desired output? Which sort key takes precedence? I don't entirely grasp why you need to sort a dictionary that has `index`es. A list is more appropriate (dictionaries are intended for O(1) lookups, not iteration), so some context would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? Or later 3.x version?

In Python 2.7 a dict is not ordered at the opposite of Python 3.x.

In Python 2.7 you will have to use an OrderedDict

Comment: @ggorlen I have editied my thread and posted my desired output as well. I am using Python 2.7